# Best way to respond to Button within listview within fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, fragment, onclicklistener

I have a `Button` in a `ListViewItem` in a `ListView` within a `Fragment`. I have code that successfully notifies the host `Activity` of the button being tapped. While the code works, I want to make sure that this is the best design pattern to use here.

Here is a summary of the code:

1. The `Activity` (`MainActivity`) passes a reference of itself (`this`) to the `Fragment` in a variable called `mainActivityReference`.
2. The `Fragment` passes this reference to the `ArrayAdapter` object in a variable also called `mainActivityReference`.
3. In the `ArrayAdapter` `getView` method, I set the `onClickListener` and call a method within the `mainActivityReference` with the index position of the item as a parameter as follows:

   ```
       viewHolder.soundButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Sound button tapped at position " + position);
               mainActivityReference.chooseSoundForIndex(position);
           }
       });
   ```

Does this seem kosher? Or should I use something like a LocalBroadcastManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic strategy of passing an "owner" object to an adapter is quite kosher, and very common. Often I will make a listener interface, and have the parent activity or fragment implement the interface. Since it is your activity that is responding to the click, you wouldn't even need to pass the reference to the fragment and then the adapter. You could just get the View's context, and check if it implements the interface. Like this:

```
public interface SoundChooser {
    void chooseSoundForIndex(int position);
}
viewHolder.soundButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Sound button tapped at position " + position);
        Context context = v.getContext();
        if (context instanceof SoundChooser) {
            ((SoundChooser)context).chooseSoundForIndex(position);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Activity should implement SoundChooser:" + context.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight and suggestion.